# How can it be determined what is causing an application (browser) to start? Event Viewer?

Tags: windows-7

After Windows loads, IE opens to home and if closed will reopen. If another app is opened, a new browser window will open to be the active window. The windows open in addition to the first window. Another app can be anything from a command prompt to windows explorer. If I try to use the open active window to navigate it returns to the home page. If I open a desktop shortcut (to another website) it will accept that navigation and treat it as home, meaning if I click a link on that site to navigate away it will return to the previous page almost immediately. System scans clean with no recent installs/updates to speak of. Did restore to a point 1 week prior to problem with no change. Even happens in Safe Mode. My apologies if I'm misusing your site, just looking for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

First, check what and when applications start automatically. The easiest way to do so is with SysInternals' (now part of MS) [Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

[image: Autoruns]

Note any process flagged by VirusTotal as being possible malware. (One or two engines might be overzealous and give false positives, but I'd be concerned over three or more indications.) Also suspicious are *unknown* processes marked in pink, but even some intrinsic Windows processes such as HelloFace Cleanup may get flagged.

If you see something causing IE to start automatically, you can uncheck the box to stop it.

*N.B.:* Even though one antimalware suite states all is copacetic, I'd try an alternative scanner, such MalwareBytes or Kaspersky free versions, possibly run from external media.

Comment: I did run MalwareBytes & AdwCleaner and Security Essentials and nothing turned up. It would not cease with rKill either. I saw AutoEuns but I couldn't understand why the link at the top of the download page said 1.5Mb while the bottom link was 1.2Mb. Guess it was an honest mistake.  I'll also try the external media. TY.

Comment: Interesting error in supposed file size... it's actually ~1.6e6 bytes now, but both links point to the same file. As it changed, they did not update the text.